# get email ID of person debuging azure data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a production and a development environment in azure data factory. I have developed the pipeline such that when the pipeline fails, we get an email notification. However the issue is if someone tests a pipeline in development and it fails we still get error email and this is bugging a lot of people as no one wants to see email of someone else's error run.

Is there a way to implement the pipeline in such a way that, if a pipeline fails in production everyone should receive an email but if a pipeline fails in development, only the developer should get the email? I cannot seem to find any system assigned variable or something like User().email just like we have in powerapps.

Please see: We cannot have a parameter in pipeline like email: <>. I need a way to get email id of the person using the pipeline dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a REST API to activity logs and get the event initiated by - which has user information of who triggered the pipeline.

Sample Request

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>/providers/Microsoft.Insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<CurrenTime - 5 mins>' and eventTimestamp le '<CURRENT TIME + 5 mins>' and resourceUri eq /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCEGROUP>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<DATAFACTORYNAME>'
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592452/get-user39s-email-dynamically.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks @abhishekKhandave-MT. I would have loved if we had direct access to user properties but this gets the job done. Thanks